# Pass a value to a mat-select to select that option Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-material

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Tipo documento</mat-label>
    <mat-select   id="select2" (selectionChange)="loadPath($event.value)" [(ngModel)]="this.valueTipDoc">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of optPath" [value]="opt.id">
        {{opt.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I have used the ngModel but it does not select anything, would there be a way to do it?

```
  this.valueTipDoc=this.data1.idPath[0].doctype.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need ngModel and name in mat - select with the same variable. For example:

```
    [(ngModel)]="valueTipDoc" name="valueTipDoc"
```

Comment: Maybe the opt.name don't its equals than value of valueTipDoc. For example, if valueTipDoc = "Document Red", you need in opt.name equals to "Document Red"